# JSON de-serialization issue

Tags: json

I'm having the issue with the JSON de-serialization process. I'm getting the JSON response is below 2 different format
ex:

the ListOfSfileadpaymentroam-Mob is sometime return as blank and sometime it return with child node and due to that I'm getting the below error message :

> common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Expected PmtBatch.ListOfSfileadpaymentroam_Mob_Out but found \"\" at [line:1, column:302]"|0x507805bc

How I can handle this different response without changing the class declaration?

Comment: Could you please paste the code you have developed till now.

Comment: Please see updated code and error message.

Comment: Paste your json response in the below link and it will generate the required apex code.
https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex

Comment: Post your wrapper class

Comment: So those aren't Lists, as sunny said put your payload in json to apex

Comment: Right, i have checked the json response with the given jsontoapex site and its also showing same class declaration. not sure where is the error and how i can handle this blank class declaration. any idea?

Comment: It appears your JSON needs to accept a List and your class isn't set up for it, if you would post the JSON in a format that I could copy and paste it would be easier

Comment: both JSON response added to the post, please check